# Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `lightblue2'

Tags: color

I am getting this error when trying to compile a TeX document using pdflatex:

> Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `lightblue2'

Here is my file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
%

%

%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
%
%
%

\enlargethispage{100cm}
% Start of code
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',line join=bevel,]
%%
\node (Wollongong) at (487bp,594bp) [draw=lightblue2,fill=lightblue2,ellipse] {Wollongong};
  \node (PDP-11 Sys V) at (884bp,306bp) [draw=lightblue2,fill=lightblue2,ellipse] {PDP-11 Sys V};
  \node (Interdata) at (258bp,594bp) [draw=lightblue2,fill=lightblue2,ellipse] {Interdata};
  \node (2*8 BSD) at (221bp,162bp) [draw=lightblue2,fill=lightblue2,ellipse] {2.8 BSD};
% CODE REMOVED TO SAVE SPACE
%
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code

%
\end{document}
%
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `LightBlue2`, not `lightblue2`.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  If you indent your code by 4 spaces, it displays in a code-like format.  Alternately, you can highlight the left-aligned code, and click the braces icon above the edit box, which will indent the highlighted code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the colour `LightBlue2`, not `lightblue2`.

Internally all colours are represented as macros and, macros are case-sensitive. That is, `\latex` is different from `\Latex` and `\LaTeX` and `\LATEX` and... In fact colour `X` is stored in a macro `\\color@X`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{LightBlue2}{something}

\makeatletter
\ttfamily\verb|\\color@LightBlue2|:
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\strip@prefix\expandafter\meaning\csname \string\color@LightBlue2\endcsname
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

See page 39 of the `xcolor` documentation for the correct color names (x11names). You'll get the documentation with running `texdoc xcolor`